# How to delete a row from csv file using del function

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I remove a row from csv file. This is the code and I want to delete row 1 of my csv file. I added del row[1] but it does not do anything. The program runs without error but does not delete row 1.

```
import csv
with open('grades.csv', 'r') as file:
    grades_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    row_num = 1
    for row in grades_reader:
        print('Row #{}:'.format(row_num), row)
        row_num += 1
        del row[1]
```

Comment: Write to the file, but without the respective row.

Comment: `del` only deletes the variable (value) in memory, not in the file.

Comment: `del row[1]` only deletes the first element of the `list` object the `csv.reader` returned and only does it to the object in memory. To delete a row from the file, you will need to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Also, what do row do you consider to be the first one? Does it matter if the CSV file has a header row?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to write the content to a temp file and then rename it

Ex:

```
import csv
import os

with open('grades.csv', 'r') as file, open('grades_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    grades_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    grades_reader_out = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(grades_reader)                                 # Header
    next(grades_reader)                                          # Skip first row
    grades_reader_out.writerow(header) #writer Header
    for row in grades_reader:
        grades_reader_out.writerow(row)

# Rename
os.rename(..., ...)
```

Comment: I don't think skipping the header is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @martineau. thanks i did not think of that

Comment: Good, that's an improvement, however the file renaming at the end won't work because the original file still exists — on my system it generates a `FileExistsError`.